# implementing reminder in mvc using quartz .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz

i want to have reminder in my website, so i decided to use quartz .net library.
i want to send specific email in specific time.
i implemented `IJob` interface using the code below

```
public class EmailJob : IJob
{
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        using (var message = new MailMessage("example@gmail.com", "example2@gmail.com"))
        {
            message.Subject = "Test";
            message.Body = "Test at " + DateTime.Now;

            using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
            {
                EnableSsl = true,
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("example@gmail.com", "password")
            })
            {
                client.Send(message);
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("HelloJob is executing.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the scheduler is like this:

```
public class JobScheduler
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler().Result;
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<EmailJob>().Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
              (s =>
                 s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
                .OnEveryDay()
                .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(0, 0))
              )
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

and in the `Application_start` i called the scheduler using the code below:
      `JobScheduler.Start();`

now, how can i see the result? i mean how can i send or receive email?
can any one help?

Comment: if job fire , send you email ? I dont understand what you mean , If you see an email in your mailbox job was successfully run.

Comment: i don't receive any email in my mailbox, and also don't get any error in my application. actually nothing happens...  @MFARKAN

Comment: Check mail sender code in Console Application.Not using with Quartz.NET.If you still do not receive e mail , code is broken or something else.